# Why use flask open_resource

Tags: python, flask

while reading flask api documentation, I came across this open_resource method that opens file, like this

```
with app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
contents = f.read()
do_something_with(contents)
```

but why not just do this?

```
with open('schema.sql') as f:
contents = f.read()
do_something_with(contents)
```

I want to see a use case where app.open_resource could do something that open can't already do

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.open_resource):

> Opens a resource from the application’s resource folder.

With `app.open_resource`, paths are always relative to the app's root (resource) folder. They may only be opened for reading, since it would be bad to be able to write to application files in production.

With `open`, relative paths are relative to the current directory. Files may be opened in any mode.